# Java: Characters in pdf cannot be rendered correctly

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdf-generation

We have a set of forms in PDF. In our program we read these forms, fill data, and then write them. We use Foxit PDF Editor to find out the font used on these forms is standard font Helvetica. When writing the forms, we set the font as follows:

```
bf=BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

The problem is: on the original forms there are some characters that we cannot identify the fonts using Foxit PDF Editor, i.e., the font property is blank for those characters. Then on the printed forms, those characters cannot be rendered correctly. In Foxit Editor, these characters has font property as "Non embedded font: EuropeanPi-Three" while we never set any font as EuropeanPi-Three when writing the PDF forms. We use package com.lowagie.text to handle pdf in java. Anyone knows how to handle this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem with iTextSharp.
The solution was in setting "substitution" font. The method is called something like **`setSubstitutionFont(BaseFont)`**.